Set CSS content only under specific conditions without Javascript
I'm using a custom stylesheet for Tree Style Tabs on Firefox. This lets me append the index number of each tab so that I can quickly access the first eight using Ctrl-<number> without having to count the tabs:
tab-item .extra-items-container.behind::after {
  background: Highlight;
  color: HighlightText;
  content: counter(vtabs);
  font: bold 90% Nina;
  line-height: 0.9;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.5ex 0.2ex;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

Is it possible to not show the numbers larger than 8? I guess I could either

Make content show counter(vtabs) only up to 8 but something like this doesn't work:
content: calc(counter(vtabs) < 9 ? counter(vtabs) : "")

Trigger the style only when the condition is satisfied, e.g. tab-item:contains("1") etc according to Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?


Neither works, though. Can anyone help please?

Are the elements you are targeting there, all siblings? And no other siblings in between? If so, you could use https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/#section7, to remove your pseudo element for elements 9 and up.
